# Single Tap on Button not calling the event handler on IOS

Tags: codenameone

I observe there is an issue with button click on iphone and ipad. Button sometimes need to be tapped twice to call the event handler. This is happening every time.Please let me know if any one notice same issue.

Thanks

Comment: Does it happen in a hello world application? Do you have a test case?